# How do I turn off autocomplete for the inputs in a form in Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For example, how would this need to change to prevent autocomplete in the name field?

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= label f, :name %>
  <%= text_input f, :name %>
  <%= error_tag f, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set `autocomplete: "off"` for both the form and text_input.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [autocomplete: "off"], fn f -> %>
  <%= label f, :name %>
  <%= text_input f, :name, autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= error_tag f, :name %>
<% end %>
```